# Unable to ping just 1 computer on the network

Tags: windows, networking, ping

I have 2 computers on the network (Computer A & B). There are also other computers on the network.

From Computer A I am able to ping all other computers on the network except Computer B. Similarly from Computer B, I am able to ping all computers on the network except Computer A.
And I am able to ping Computer A & Computer B from other machines in the network.

It looks like just Computer A & Computer B won't talk to each other for some reason. I have done the following and still have problems:

1. Re-installed Operating systems in both Computers. Computer A was upgraded to Windows Server 2012 from Server 2008 R2. Windows Server 2008 R2 was re-installed in Computer B.
2. Firewall is turned off in both computers

Does anybody know why this would happen?

Comment: Switch ?LAN ? Network config ?

Comment: Both are connected to LAN

Comment: Whats their subnet configurations ?

Comment: 255.255.255.0. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: After attempt to connect, look at ARP on both hosts.
   arp -a

Comment: Yeah, compare to the rest of the computers in the network

Comment: Checked with arp -a. Pinged from Computer A to Computer B, and from Computer C (another Computer on network) to B, and both (A & C) show the same physical address for Computer B and type is dynamic. Also pinged from Computer B to Computer A, and from Computer C (another Computer on network) to A, and both (B & C) show the same physical address for Computer A and type is dynamic.

Comment: However, I am able to lookup the IP address of the machines using nslookup. I am just not able to ping. From A to B, I get the message "Request timed out.". From B to A, I get the message "Destination Host Unreachable".

Comment: Open cmd and run "ipconfig" and post the local ipv4's listed from machine A and B -> please also post standard gateway

Comment: Computer A - IPv4: xx.xx.4.30, Default Gateway: xx.xx.4.252. Computer B - IPv4: xx.xx.4.59, Default Gateway: xx.xx.4.252

Comment: you've confirmed that they don't have the same mac address right? do they both use the same subnetmask, and does it end in .0?

Comment: Yes, both have the same subnet mask 255.255.255.0

Comment: They have different MAC address

Comment: Are you pinging by hostname or IP address?

Comment: By IP address from both machines

Comment: Maybe another approach: Check the settings of the normal pc's against the settings of computers A and B...i would start with basic network settings and then onto firewall software, settings etc.

Comment: Ok. I connected Machine B from another location in the network and I am able to ping now...however I don't know why only Machine A was unable to ping Machine B in the previous location...